# How can I make my custom font support on bold or put multiple fonts?

Tags: swift, text, fonts, textview, uitextview

I want to use in my project text view with the custom font- heebo.
but I have a problem when I run my app all the bold word is not bolded
and everting is hebbo regular, how can I fix it or make this font to be multiple?

another solution is to write a function that takes the text inside of the text view and detect if its bold or regular and if its bold I put heebo-bold.ttf and if not I put heebo-reguler.ttf so if somebody helps me with that it will be good.

Comment: How are you trying to set the font? Is it declared on your project?

Comment: I just put my text on the textView in my storyboard, nad choose heebo font, I have also in my project 5 hebbo style ttf files

Comment: You can try to add the font filenames on your info.plist as you can see on this link: https://bencoding.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/customfonts.png (build and retry)

Comment: I do it before it's steel not recognize the bold text.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the very same font you're trying (Heebo bold) and I've done the next steps:

1. Install font on the system (double click on .ttf file)
2. Copy the font to your project folder on xcode. (Make sure you're checking Copy items if needed and add to target 'your target' check boxes)
3. Add hebo-bold.ttf to your info.plist under "Fonts provided by application" (as in next image)
   [image]
4. Build (cmd + B)
5. Use font from **storyboard** or by **code**:

   yourLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Heebo-Bold", size: 18.0)

When you want to know the exact name a font has (when setting it by code you need this name not the filename like 'heebo-bold.ttf') you can use these couple of lines:

```
print(UIFont.familyNames) 

print(UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "familyName"))
```

First line will print the names of all family fonts available.
Second line will tell you the specific name you'll have to use on UIFont(name: String, size: CGFloat) (i.e. Heebo-Bold, Heebo-Italic, etc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want that my text will be integrated with heebo-regular and heebo-bold